# How to change Profile layout

Tags: salesforce

When I'm selecting particular profile from Profile's list(**manage users-profiles**)

it looks like this

[image]

In one tutorial I saw it looks differently

[image]

how to change my  layout on second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to enable [Enhanced Profile User Interface](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_profiles_about_enhanced_ui.htm).

In the setup menus, under "Customize", click "User Interface". The Enanced Profile User Interface will be one of many checkboxes on that page.